# Rails form (select/option) - how to mark selected option with HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, haml

What's the quickest and most elegant way to mark currently selected option value in the form in HAML?

```
%form{:action => '', :method => 'get'}
   %select{:name => 'param_name'}
      %option{:value => 'A'} A data
      %option{:value => 'B'} B data
```

One way:

```
- if params[:param_name] == "A"
  %option{:value => 'A', :selected => 'selected'} A data
- else
  %option{:value => 'A'} A data
```

but this is inappropriate when the `select` box will has many option fields.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this will work (using the older "hashrocket syntax" with the operator `=>`)

```
%select
  %option{:value => "a", :selected => params[:x] == "a"}= "a"
  %option{:value => "b", :selected => params[:x] == "b"}= "b"
```

Or, in newer Ruby versions (1.9 and greater):

```
%select
  %option{value: "a", selected: params[:x] == "a"}= "a"
  %option{value: "b", selected: params[:x] == "b"}= "b"
```

Comment: what does the selected:params[:x] do?

Comment: the default selected value. the value for selected can be true or false (which the == evaluates to)

Answer (score 18):

You should unleash the power of rails helpers.

[For `select` tag](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease):

```
= select_tag :param_name, options_for_select([['A data', 'A'], ['B data', 'B']], params[:param_name])
```

Also, instead of raw `%form` use `form_tag` or better `form_for` when it's possible (or more better simple_form or formtastic)

Comment: This answer is certainly preferable to writing raw form markup in views, if you are able to use the form helpers.

Comment: love the answer would be nicer if it had an example of wrapping it in a `form_tag` or `form_for`, the HAML syntax is pretty annoying with its indentation